# Facebook Open Graph date format

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When generating a meta tag for `article:published_time` or `og:updated_time`, in what format should I put the time. Some documentation in Facebook says it should be in Unix epoch and other documentation suggest is should be in ISO 8601.

`<meta property="og:updated_time" content="1414056907" />` or

`<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2013-01-22T09:10:08+0100" />`

Thank you for looking in to this.

Sander

Comment: http://ogp.me/#type_article

Answer (score 9):

I recommend using the **ISO 8601** date format as specified in OpenGraph official documentation (see here : http://ogp.me/#data_types).

I tested it successfully with the facebook sharer function to force the crawler to get a new image.

Answer (score 5):

While I agree with the logic of the last answer, when using the tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ we see that a meta tag reading

`<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2015-04-07T13:19:06-04:00" />`

is converted to `1428432011` when FaceBook reads it.

That is not to say, use the integer value.  However, if Facebook is the reason you are wondering, it seems not to matter.